# What is the general philosophy with images on the tag info page?

Tags: discussion

New to reviewing tag edits so looking for some guidance. Noticed some edits inserting rather large images to tag info pages. The [google-chrome](https://superuser.com/tags/google-chrome/info) was not one I reviewed but an example of a really large image.

Questions are:

- Should edits with just a large image (assuming appropriate) be approved or rejected
- Any general guidelines on image size

My personal preference would be to use a smaller icon to not distract from the text but wanted others opinions.

Comment: Size looks fine to me. As long as it isn't *much* wider than the display area, it's fine. If it's a screenshot, or something that should be viewed enlarged, it should be linked to a larger version.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg something like the [Windows 7](http://superuser.com/tags/windows-7/info) seems like a better fit. Maybe thats just me.

Comment: See: [Company logos on tag wikis; are they allowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130623/company-logos-on-tag-wikis-are-they-allowed)

Comment: Well, I just resized the logo, it was way too large IMO.

Comment: I agreed & approved your pending edit, the current one is just *way* too big.  I think this practice is acceptable if we have a practical height limit on the logo images.  And visually, I think the one @BradPatton has modified is perfect (and significantly less distracting).  I think the logos are important to include if available, since it is a key identifying characteristic of any program/product/business.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reject.

There is no reason to make the tag wiki info page a product sales pitch. An image serves no purpose.

A tag wiki should include

- what type of question the tag is best used on
- any other related tags they might go with
- related tags they could find answers through
- resources about the product, such as books, links or tutorials
- brief description of the product

In that order or importance.

Comment: I'd be OK with a small, tasteful logo, but in that Chrome example the logo is just way too big.

Comment: +1:  The Google Chrome logo should be immediately noticeable to most internet users, and they won't mind it being dialed back.  The rest of them won't recognize it and won't care that it is dialed back, especially if more information is being provided as to what the heck this thing is.  So, small good, big annoying.